# Forcing disable of Google Account synchronization of extension on a per-extension basis

Tags: google-chrome-extension, synchronization, enterprise, google-account, group-policy

We have authored a Chrome extension and would like to ensure that our extension does not at any time participate in being sync'd using Google Account synchronization, even if the user has specified in the Advanced sync settings dialog that extensions be sync'd.  Is there a way to prevent this sync'ing on a per-extension basis?  Is there some setting we could place in the extension manifest file to accomplish this?  Or other way to accomplish this?

If that is not possible, can we force the Extensions checkbox to always be unchecked and unalterable by the user, using enterprise-level techniques such as Group Policy Update?  This is not optimal, since we only want to stop the sync'ing of our extension, and not prevent sync'ing of all extensions.

We do see that the SyncDisabled policy registry setting is available to us, but that looks like it will disable ALL data synchronization including Apps, Extensions, Settings, History, etc.  This is even less desirable to us, since we don't want to affect other synchronization -- we just want to prevent only our extension from being sync'd.

The use case for this involves the following:
A corporate user installs Chrome on his work computer.  Our extension is useful in the enterprise environment and is installed on Chrome.
At some point, using the Chrome browser, this user logs into his personal Gmail account.  He has set up his Google Account to turn synchronization on.
Now when this user, using his home computer and Chrome browser, logs in to Google, he will find that our extension has also been installed on his Chrome browser at home -- this is not desirable, since our extension has no usefulness in the home environment.  Moreover, the user may consider the presence of our extension an unwanted intrusion into his home computing environment.
The only remedy for this user would seem to be that he could go to the Advanced sync settings and uncheck the Extensions checkbox, but then he would lose the benefit of extension sync'ing of other extensions, which he may want.

Answer (score 1):

Well, if you're doing it in a corporate / managed environment, you don't need to publish your extension on Web Store at all (thus preventing the sync) if you can use Group Policy.

Any extension in [`ExtensionInstallForcelist`](http://dev.chromium.org/administrators/policy-list-3#ExtensionInstallForcelist) will be installed even if it (and its update manifest) is hosted outside Web Store. This will prevent the extension itself from syncing (though will probably still allow `chrome.storage.sync` to function for it, which is a plus).

Other than that, I don't think there's a way to prevent an individual Store-hosted extension from syncing.